# Sorting/Cluster a 2D numpy array in ordered sequence based on multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, sequence

I have a 2D numpy array like this:

```
 [[4 5 2] 
  [5 5 1]
  [5 4 5]
  [5 3 4]
  [5 4 4]
  [4 3 2]]
```

I would like to sort/cluster this array by finding the sequence in array like this `row[0]>=row[1]>=row[2]`, `row[0]>=row[2]>row[1]`... so the row of the array is in ordered sequence.

I tried to use the code: `lexdf = df[np.lexsort((df[:,2], df[:,1],df[:,0]))][::-1]`, however it is not I want.
The output of lexsort:

```
 [[5 5 1]
  [5 4 5]
  [5 4 4]
  [5 3 4]
  [4 5 2] 
  [4 3 2]]
```

The output I would like to have:

```
 [[5 5 1]
  [5 4 4]
  [4 3 2]
  [5 4 5]
  [5 3 4]
  [4 5 2]]
```

or cluster it into three parts:

```
 [[5 5 1]
 [5 4 4]
 [4 3 2]]

 [[5 4 5]
 [5 3 4]]

 [[4 5 2]]
```

And I would like to apply this to an array with more columns, so it would be better to do it without iteration. Any ideas to generate this kind of output?

Comment: Your notation is non standard, which makes it hard to follow your description

Comment: What is `row[0]>=row[1]>=row[2]` all about?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I would like to sort the rows in the 2D array based on the column. So `row[0]>=row[1]>row[2]` means to find the rows in this array, that the value in the first column is larger or equal to value in the second column, and value in the second column larger than the value the thrid column.

Comment: I still don't understand how you get from that to the desired output. Perhaps you could write a comparator function that you could use for sorting, or a sort key? Basically unambiguously show how you would decide which row comes first.

Comment: Sound like a graph problem: Given a directed graph, partition the graph into simple trees (without any branches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in numpy, except maybe with some weird hacks of function `numpy.split`.

Here is a way to get your groups with python lists:

```py
from itertools import groupby, pairwise

def f(sublist):
    return [x <= y for x,y in pairwise(sublist)]

# NOTE: itertools.pairwise requires python>=3.10
# For python<=3.9, use one of those alternatives:
# * more_itertools.pairwise(sublist)
# * zip(sublist, sublist[1:])

a = [[4, 5, 2], 
  [5, 5, 1],
  [5, 4, 5],
  [5, 3, 4],
  [5, 4, 4],
  [4, 3, 2]]

b = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(a, key=f), key=f)]

print(b)
# [[[4, 3, 2]],
#  [[5, 4, 5], [5, 3, 4], [5, 4, 4]],
#  [[4, 5, 2], [5, 5, 1]]]
```

Note: The combination groupby+sorted is actually slightly subefficient, because `sorted` takes n log(n) time. A linear alternative is to group using a dictionary of lists. See for instance [function `itertoolz.groupby` from module `toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.groupby).

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed what I need. Just a minor thing, if I want to have my desired output it should be `x < y` not `x <= y`.  I would like to ask one more thing if it is possible: if I would like to only compare the first several columns' values not the entire column what should I do? For example I only want to compare the first two columns.

Comment: I have already found the way! Thanks for your insight!